# Ubuntu 12.04 on asus n76vb fan speed not working

Tags: asus, fancontrol, lm-sensors

I instaled lm-sensors followed everyting

```
1@ubuntu:~$ sudo sensors-detect 
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
# sensors-detect revision 5984 (2011-07-10 21:22:53 +0200)
# System: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. N76VB (laptop)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): yes
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
(driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): yes
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): yes
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): yes
Found unknown SMBus adapter 8086:1e22 at 0000:00:1f.3.
Sorry, no supported PCI bus adapters found.

Next adapter: i915 gmbus ssc (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus vga (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): yes
Client found at address 0x49
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM75'...                yeNo
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM75A'...               No
Probing for `Dallas Semiconductor DS75'...                  sNo
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM77'...                No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7410'...                     No
Probing for `Dallas Semiconductor DS1621/DS1631'...         No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6642'...                              No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM73'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM92'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM76'...                No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6633/MAX6634/MAX6635'...              No
Probing for `NXP/Philips SA56004'...                        No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1023'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1043'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1053'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1063'...                               No
Client found at address 0x50
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1033'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1034'...                     No
Probing for `SPD EEPROM'...                                 No
Probing for `EDID EEPROM'...                                Yes
    (confidence 8, not a hardware monitoring chip)

Next adapter: i915 gmbus panel (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): yes
Client found at address 0x50
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1033'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1034'...                     No
Probing for `SPD EEPROM'...                                 No
Probing for `EDID EEPROM'...                                Yes
(confidence 8, not a hardware monitoring chip)

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpc (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpb (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpd (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): yes

Next adapter: DPDDC-C (i2c-6)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): yes

Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
 contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)yes
Successful!

Monitoring programs won't work until the needed modules are
loaded. You may want to run 'service module-init-tools start'
 to load them.

 Unloading cpuid... OK
```

then

```
 sudo service module-init-tools restart
```

then

```
sensor
```

and i get this response

```
 acpitz-virtual-0
 Adapter: Virtual device
 temp1:        +46.0 C  (crit = +108.0 C)

 coretemp-isa-0000
 Adapter: ISA adapter
 Physical id 0:  +46.0 C  (high = +87.0 C, crit = +105.0 C)
 Core 0:         +46.0 C  (high = +87.0 C, crit = +105.0 C)
 Core 1:         +45.0 C  (high = +87.0 C, crit = +105.0 C)
 Core 2:         +43.0 C  (high = +87.0 C, crit = +105.0 C)
 Core 3:         +44.0 C  (high = +87.0 C, crit = +105.0 C)

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
temp1:        +46.0 C
```

then i installed

```
 fancontrol
```

and when i tryed to run

```
 sudo pwmconfig



 This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
 controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
 your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
 circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

 We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
 The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
 after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
 physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
 after the program has completed.

 /usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no fan-capable sensor modules installed
```

adn i can not find a way to make my fan change speed

can someone help me

i dont know if its due to the chipset or configuration

- Asus n67vb
- Intel® Core™ i7 3630QM Processor
- Intel® HM76 Chipset
- DDR3 1600 MHz SDRAM 12GB
- NVIDIA® GeForce® GT 740M with 4GB DDR3 VRAM

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu that you are using? And what is the exact issue that you're having? Does the fan does NOT work at all, or is it just misbehaving (i.e. fanning always too much)?

Comment: i forgot to mark as solved , but after a couple of updates it started working fine ... now im on 13.10 and its working as it should

Comment: Could you add the steps to solve the issue (installed updates of what packages, etc.) and then accept your own answer? I may soon get myself a laptop with the same nVidia graphics card, so I'm very interested in the solution.

Comment: @landroni basicly there is only the processor fan that turn on because the graphic are manly rendered with hd4000 and i have one fan for cpu and gpu  so it depend on witch laptop you will get but for me other sensors dictate the fan speed